# Permanent file directory in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, file, path

In the documents directory for my app, I have a file Q1.dat which I use in my program. I access it through the path:

```
func createArrayPath () -> String? {
    if let docsPath: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).last {
        return ((docsPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("Q1") as NSString).stringByAppendingPathExtension("dat")
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I run the program on a different device however, a different documents directory is created, and the file is no longer present. Is there a place I can put the file so that I can always access it no matter what device I am running on?

Comment: Maybe use iCloud? How do you expect the devices to share data?

Comment: Is there a way for the user to download the file as well when they download the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Documents directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html) is meant for data created by the user.

It sounds like you want to bundle a [resource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html) with your application. You can do this by simply [dragging the file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_File_or_Folder.html) into Xcode, which will automatically set it up to be copied into your app bundle, and you can find it using [`URLForResource(_:withExtension:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:).

If the file is very large, you might want it to be downloaded separately from the main app. For this you can use the new [On-Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/) feature.

Comment: Could I find the path for the file by saying path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Q1", withExtension: "dat")!.path!

Comment: Yes, but (a) don't use `!` because you are ignoring errors, and (b) don't use `path`, just use `NSData(contentsOfURL: ...)` to read the data.

Comment: So I can just drag the file into the main folder for the project, right next to Assets.xcassets and it should find it?

Comment: Have you tried it?   You might also find [this article](http://www.meandmark.com/bundlespart2.html) useful.